# MetaMask transaction rejected

Tags: metamask

Why transactions are rejected in MetaMask after conforming it?
When a transaction is carried out in metamask it first get approved. after sometime it shows rejected.
metamask is showing something like this

[image]

anyone know the reason for rejecting these transactions???

Comment: Can you give the transaction ID? Most likely ran out of gas or bad instruction jump on the transaction itself.

Comment: transaction ID : 0x5E72914535f202659083Db3a02C984188Fa26e9f

Answer (score 0):

If you hover your cursor over the red "(Rejected)" message, MetaMask will show you the reason it was rejected.

Comment: In my case it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

On October 4th there was one successful transaction to 0x5E72914535f202659083Db3a02C984188Fa26e9f according to etherscan: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd1d91c14d3106e59b6a345f694d5b5fac2c2126d162d3f280504f2097c1db150.

Are you switching metamask between different networks? Sometimes the transaction history somehow gets confused when using the same accounts on different networks. It might help if you restore your account from the 12 word seed to get rid of the wrong entries. To do this, lock your account, click "forgot password", enter seed phrase.